# Not sure if the question below is more opinion based, or can actually get proper answers

Tags: discussion

I have a question, regarding inclusion of js frameworks in extensions - that looks like a best practices question. I think however that a few thorough answers could help developers on making the proper decision when developing their extensions.

Could the question below exist on JSE ? :

> How to deal with the JS frameworks inclusions in extensions in Joomla
>   3?
>
> In Joomla 3 the mootools library has been deprecated. Instead Joomla
>   relies on Bootstrap and jQuery. There is always the risk when
>   injecting other scripts in the head, to disturb the order of the
>   scripts and end up with js conflicts.
>
> What is the best practice to include other libraries for an extension,
>   that does not use Bootstrap or jQuery, while other
>   extensions/templates will load them?
>
> Should the developer of an extension that relies on other frameworks
>   and not on Bootstrap/jQuery consider that the website might make use
>   of them, and code the extension in in such a way to ensure no js
>   conflicts?
>
> For example it seems to me that a backend setting in the extension
>   asking the user if the website makes use of these frameworks already,
>   could enable the appropriate inclusion of these libraries in the view
>   of the extension.
>
> But should that be a standard approach when developing extensions, or
>   what could be the alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the general type of question is acceptable, but that you should not try to make the question actual general. (Not sure if that is a logical sentence...)

In other words, don't try to make the question general. Ask about what you are trying to actually do. For example:

> I am trying to include `X` javascript library in my extension.
>
> How can I include this javascript library in a way that it won't impact other extensions negatively?

There likely isn't an answer to how to do this for ALL frameworks, but there could be good answers to how to do it for A framework. So ask for what you are actually interested in.

Ideally, you could even go a step further and show how you are trying to implement this and discuss any issues you are having.